# How can I create a boxplot on only positive values in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot on about 10 variables where only positive values are considered within each variable. This changes from variable to variable, So something that is 0 in one category might be positive in another.

To do it for one variable looks like this so far;

```
ax=sns.boxplot(data=[df['Category_1_value'][df['Category_1_value'] > 0]])
```

I could do the above 10 times but hoped there was an easier way.

Is there a simple option to just ignore the 0 values within each category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider replacing all negative values with `np.nan` before plotting:

```
df[df < 0] = np.nan

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
sns.boxplot(data=df, ax=ax)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

---

To demonstrate with random, seeded data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(102918)    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5))
df.columns = ['Category_'+ str(i) +'_value' for i in range(1, 6)]

print(df.head(5)
#    Category_1_value  Category_2_value  Category_3_value  Category_4_value  Category_5_value
# 0         -0.911648         -0.453908         -0.495518          0.733304          0.569576
# 1          0.780117         -0.079954          0.134944         -1.764539         -0.267812
# 2         -0.256881          0.470838          0.437137          1.295758          0.385070
# 3         -1.665858         -1.001672         -0.444930          0.758346          0.132343
# 4         -0.167982          1.033756          1.636315          0.458918          0.022343

df[df < 0] = np.nan

print(df.head(5))
#    Category_1_value  Category_2_value  Category_3_value  Category_4_value  Category_5_value
# 0               NaN               NaN               NaN          0.733304          0.569576
# 1          0.780117               NaN          0.134944               NaN               NaN
# 2               NaN          0.470838          0.437137          1.295758          0.385070
# 3               NaN               NaN               NaN          0.758346          0.132343
# 4               NaN          1.033756          1.636315          0.458918          0.022343
```

**Plot**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
sns.boxplot(data=df, ax=ax)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]